# Использование werkzeug secure_filename с русскими символами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Оказалось, что `secure_filename` не дружит с не ascii символами:

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

file_name = "Шаблон описание commits дизайнера.txt"
filename = secure_filename(file_name)
print(filename)  #  commits_.txt
```

[Функция используется при загрузке файла на сервер через html страницу используя flask](http://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/patterns/fileuploads/). На странице через input'ы указывается файл и отправляется. А `secure_filename` использовалась чтобы обезопасить сервер от имени файла.
Вебсервер будет располагаться на Windows.

Хотелось бы узнать какие есть аналоги этой функции. Не исключаю, что придется писать свой аналог.

Comment: `secure_filename()` ведёт себя [как задокументировано](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/dev/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) (фактически используются символы, разрешённые для переносимых имён файлов в POSIX: `[A-Za-z_.-]`). Если у вас другие требования, то явно их укажите. Какой контекст: откуда имя берётся, как позже используется. Какие файловые системы, OS? Хотите рассматривать: `'ё.txt'` и `'ё.txt'` как одинаковые имена или разные? Хотите поддерживать не-BMP символы, суррогатные пары?

Comment: @jfs, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: ...и добавил ссылку на которой брал пример загрузки файлов через flask

Comment: Не ясно как дальше имя используется. Если упростить, что мешает просто случайно сгенерированные имена использовать? (а  имя, предоставляемое пользователем в базу писать как есть)

Comment: Наверное, я так и сделаю -- для файлов буду генерировать случайные имена, а в базу заносить сгенерированное имя и то, которое придумал пользователь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно переписать функцию `secure_filename`, добавив в нее поддержку кириллицы

Пример:

```
import sys
import os
import re


PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
if PY2:
    text_type = unicode
else:
    text_type = str

_windows_device_files = (
    "CON",
    "AUX",
    "COM1",
    "COM2",
    "COM3",
    "COM4",
    "LPT1",
    "LPT2",
    "LPT3",
    "PRN",
    "NUL",
)

_filename_strip_re = re.compile(r"[^A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9_.-]")


def secure_filename(filename: str) -> str:
    if isinstance(filename, text_type):
        from unicodedata import normalize
        filename = normalize("NFKD", filename)

    for sep in os.path.sep, os.path.altsep:
        if sep:
            filename = filename.replace(sep, " ")

    filename = str(_filename_strip_re.sub("", "_".join(filename.split()))).strip(
        "._"
    )
    
    if (
        os.name == "nt"
        and filename
        and filename.split(".")[0].upper() in _windows_device_files
    ):
        filename = f"_{filename}"

    return filename
```

Проверка:

```
file_name = "Шаблон описание commits дизайнера.txt"
filename = secure_filename(file_name)
print(filename)
# Шаблон_описание_commits_дизаинера.txt
```

Comment: Благодарю.
(С)тырю!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, пожалуйста :)