# Проблема с кирилическими именами файлов при загрузке в flask

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, flask

Есть необходимость загружать файлы на сервер в том числе с кирилическими именами. В процесе загрузки используется функция `secure_filename()` которая насколько я понимаю проверяе что имена файлов не содержать вредоносных команд. Данная функция не пропускает кирилические имена файлов. Можно ли её как либо настроить чтобы использовать с кирилическими именами или прийдется от неё отказаться?

```
filename = file.filename
logging.debug('Before secure %s', filename)
filename = secure_filename(filename)
logging.debug('After secure %s', filename)
```

Вывод:

```
2017-02-14 18:51:56,296 - DEBUG - Before secure ыыыы.csv
2017-02-14 18:51:56,301 - DEBUG - After secure csv
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Использование werkzeug secure_filename с русскими символами](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587855/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция secure_filename() из werkzeug.utils возвращает строку ASCII символов, см [документацию](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/dev/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename). Любые не ASCII символы, в частности, кириллические символы из входной строки будут удалены. Вы не сможете использовать secure_filename() в своем приложении.